# What did the SELECT command do in DOS?

Tags: ms-dos, books

The introduction to Greg Harvey’s *DOS for Dummies: Quick Reference* (also subtitled *Command Reference* in the first edition) contains this passage:

> This book not only gives you the lowdown on each and every DOS command — excepting DELOLDOS, FDISK and SELECT, a trio of commands I guarantee you’ll never miss […]

(Another edition I remember having at one point also lists `DEBUG` here.)

Now, `DEBUG` and `FDISK` are pretty well-known. As for `DELOLDOS`, the command name is suggestive enough for me to guess its purpose is to delete any previous versions of DOS after an upgrade, and some web searching [confirms this](https://www.infania.net/misc/kbarchive/kb/070/Q70753/index.html). As for `SELECT` though, I am stumped. This is not an internal command of COMMAND.COM, and yet there is not a SELECT.COM or SELECT.EXE executable on any of my four MS-DOS 6.22 installation disks either; nothing is also mentioned in the online help system (HELP.COM). At one point I even started to suspect this might have been a misprint.

Where did this `SELECT` command come from? What did it do? Was this a real command at all?

Comment: Not to be confused with the [`SELECT`](https://jpsoft.com/help/select.htm) command that some may have enjoyed with 4DOS, of course.  (-:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT` was introduced in IBM PC DOS 3.0, along with internationalisation support, and made available in MS-DOS starting with version 3.3.

Its purpose is to create a bootable disk with support for a given country code and keyboard layout. The syntax, starting with version 3.2, is

```
SELECT [[drive1:] drive2:[path]] country keyboard
```

where `drive1` is the source drive (`A` by default), `drive2` the destination drive (`B` by default), `country` is one of the supported country codes (033 for France, 049 for Germany — West Germany at the time — etc.), and `keyboard` is one of the available keyboards (`FR`, `GR` etc.).

This was effectively the installation procedure for floppy-based versions of DOS, outside the US: prepare a blank floppy, boot with DOS disk 1, and run `SELECT` with the appropriate country and keyboard code. This would result in a usable DOS disk, with all the contents of DOS disk 1, and a correctly-configured keyboard as soon as the system was booted.

[image: Screenshot of MS-DOS 3.3 SELECT installing to a hard drive]

Version 3.0 and 3.1 of `SELECT` use `DISKCOPY` to copy the source disk to the destination disk, formatting the latter if necessary. Version 3.2 and 3.3 use `FORMAT` and `XCOPY` instead; version 3.3 supports hard drives (although running `FDISK` is left as an exercise for the user, before running `SELECT`). In both cases, the destination disk is erased, and all the contents of the source disk are copied, not only the files required to support the desired country and keyboard. In version 3.2, if the source disk doesn’t include the `KEYBxx` file required for the desired keyboard, the user is prompted to instead the disk containing it. All versions then write an appropriate `CONFIG.SYS` and `AUTOEXEC.BAT` to the target disk, containing respectively

```
COUNTRY=<country>
```

(adding the `COUNTRY.SYS` path too if necessary), and

```
PATH ...
KEYB...
ECHO OFF
DATE
TIME
VER
```

The default path (`PATH` above) depends on the installation path (the second parameter).

In version 4.0 of PC DOS and MS-DOS, `SELECT` became an interactive installation tool, which was started automatically from the installation disk (or the “Select” disk on 5.25” disk sets).

In version 5.0 of PC DOS and MS-DOS, the setup program was renamed to `SETUP.EXE` and introduced support for upgrading DOS. This is where `DELOLDOS` comes from: when upgrading, `SETUP` would create `DELOLDOS`, which could be used to undo the upgrade, restoring the previous version of DOS (and its boot sector etc.).

There appears to have been another version of `SELECT`, written by Karl D. Wright for Phoenix Technologies, and included in at least some OEM versions of MS-DOS 3.2; a quick look through it suggests it does the same thing as the “official” `SELECT`.

According to *The MS-DOS Encyclopedia*, `SELECT` was available in PC DOS 2.0, but my PC DOS 2 disks don’t have it and there wouldn’t have been much use for it on PC DOS 2 which didn’t have either the `COUNTRY` statement or the `KEYBxx` commands.

Comment: Good answer, as usual. I do think I remember PC-DOS 2 already having select - that would be the version with fixed disk drives (Source A:, destination B:)

Comment: According to my documentation (including the PC DOS manuals), DOS 2 didn’t have it, 3.0 added it, and 3.0 and 3.1 had fixed drive selections. See page 7-162 of [the PC DOS 3.10 Reference](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/pc/dos/6138519_DOS_3.10_Reference_Feb85.pdf) (I can’t find the 3.0 manual online).

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR;

> Where did this SELECT command come from?

PC-DOS

> What did it do?

Install DOS on a blank drive as a complete bootdrive including language/country specific files.

> Was this a real command at all?

Yes.

---

### Long story:

`SELECT` was essentially like a `FORMAT /S`, which also copies necessary files like `KEYBGR` for German keyboard or `COUNTRY.SYS` and creates fitting `AUTOEXEC.BAT` and `CONFIG.SYS` with appropriate settings for keyboard and display.

To my memory `SELECT` was only available for IBM's PC-DOS and only worked from diskette drives, with `A:` hard coded as source for all files and `B:` as destination.

Later PC-DOS (3?) versions allowed the selection of source and destination drive, so it could be used for hard disk install. Again later, the fixed function utility controlled by command line was replaced by an interactive installer of the same name, to be finally (DOS 6?) replaced by `SETUP`.

---

This installer / SETUP was also what brought `DELOLDOS`, as only they did copy any previous DOS installation on the target drive into a folder called `OLD_DOS`. `DELOLDOS` checked if that folder is to be found on the logged drive. If yes, it deleted the folder and in turn itself. So usually hard to find - especially if someone used it on a system :)

Comment: "To my memory select was only available for IBM's PC-DOS and only worked from diskette drives, with A: hard coded as source for all files and B: as destination." -- according to the website I linked below, it was available for MS DOS as well, and the MS DOS version allowed you to specify the drives and did allow a fixed disk as destination.

Comment: @MichaelGraf That page does not specify which MS-DOS version did offer it first, and what version did offer which functionality. As such it doesn't contradict my memory. PC-DOS had it prior to MS-DOS, and HD support was only added later on. (Reading in full also helps to understand what has been said)

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the [DEW Associates MS DOS support site from 1998](http://www.dewassoc.com/support/msdos/select.htm#:%7E:text=Purpose%3A%20Formats%20a%20disk%20and,on%20the%20DOS%20supplemental%20disk.&text=SELECT%20transfers%20country%2Dspecific%20information,the%20program%20transfers%20the%20CONFIG.): SELECT "formats a disk and installs country-specific information and keyboard codes."

This is relevant only when you want to boot from a floppy disk. SYS would make this disk bootable, but not copy the configuration files, which you would then have to copy by hand. SELECT does this for you.

By the time MS DOS 6.22 came around, this use case was pretty much nonexistent; everyone was booting from hard disks. The website above notes that "in DOS Version 6, this command is stored on the DOS supplemental disk", which may be why you couldn't find it; or maybe it was removed altogether.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `SELECT` disappeared in DOS 5, even from the supplemental disks.

Comment: The functionality of SELECT was incorporated into some SETUP versions.  DOS 5 did not have supplemental disks.  This is a feature of MS-DOS 6 and PC-DOS 7.  Up to then they issued CSD (corrective service disks), or downloadable patches.

Comment: @Wendy I have a three-disk OEM MS-DOS 5 set where the third disk is labeled as “supplemental”; that’s what I was referring to. (And no, it’s not the third disk in the standard 3.5” DD distribution; this is a 3.5” HD distribution.)

Comment: @StephenKitt  OEMs were known to feed various utilities like 'park' and alternate file managers / menus / utilities / help files into a 'supplemental' disk or a disk named something like GWBASIC.  It's not standard thing you could download from MSFT.

Comment: @Wendy like I said, I *am* referring to the kind of supplemental disk provided by OEMs, since those sometimes included utilities that Microsoft had removed from the corresponding “official” DOS release (hence their relevance to this Q&A, since one might have found `SELECT` there after Microsoft removed it). I never mentioned downloading anything from Microsoft.